# Efficiently filter 3D matrix in numpy with variable 2D masks

Tags: python, numpy, 3d, filtering

I have a **3D numpy array points of dimensions [10000x3000x128]** where the first dimension is the number of frames, the second dimension the number of points in each frame and the third dimension is a 128-element feature vector associated to each point. What I want to do is to **efficiently filter the points in each frame by using a boolean 2D mask** of dimensions [10000x3000] and for each of the selected points also take the related 128-dim vector of features. Moreover, **in output I need still a 3D vector** and not a merged 2D vector and possibly **avoid any for loop**.
Actually what I'm doing is:

```
# example of points
points = np.array([10000, 3000, 128])

# fg, bg = 2D dimensional boolean np.array

# init empty lists
fg_points, bg_points = [], []

for i in range(points.shape[0]):
     fg_mask_tmp, bg_mask_tmp = fg[i], bg[i]
     fg_points.append(points[i,fg_mask_tmp,:])
     bg_points.append(points[i,bg_mask_tmp,:])

fg_features, bg_features = np.array(fg_points), np.array(bg_points)
```

But this is a quite naive solution that for sure can be improved in a more numpy-like way.
In addition, I also tried other solutions as:

```
fg_features = points[fg,:]
```

But this solution does not preserve the dimensions of the array merging the two first dimensions since the **number of filtered points for each frame can vary**.
Another solution I tried is to enlarge the 2D masks by appending a [128] true value to the last dimension, but with any successful result.
Dos anyone know a possible efficient solution?

Thank you in advance for any help!